# Does this expression makes sense?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

> W : I'm impressed at how expertly you played that piano sonata.
>
> M : **Sorry. I'm still just an apprentice**.

When the man says "sorry", what does this exactly mean in this circumstances?
Is it kind of a humble expression I can use when praised?

One more question,

> W : Mr. Smith, the tiles in the restaurant bathroom need to be replaced.
> M : Why? There's nothing wrong with them.
> W : Yes, but they're starting to look old.
> **M : I don't think that warrants the expense.**

Does this mean "That is not enough for changing the whole tiles."?
Do you frequently use this expression?

Comment: Please ask 1 question at a a time. What did the dictionary say about warrant (synonym of justify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self depreciation was exactly the pianist's meaning. His use of the word sorry was unnecessary and, in general, is overused in the US.
The person in your second example is expressing his opinion that a preference for new tile is not a sufficient reason to buy new tile or to replace the tile with something else.  My observation is that warrant is commonly used--maybe partly because we are all so familiar with the word warranty?  Use may be less common among young adults and teens.

Answer (score 2):

The term for his comment is **[self-deprecating](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/self-deprecating)**

> Tending to undervalue oneself and one's abilities. [*American Heritage Dictionary*]

The comment is a mild apology for lack of skill and may reflect actual or false modesty.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the first question, about the use of *Sorry*, it's an expression of incredulity used in the sense of "Pardon? I didn't quite catch that. Would you repeat it please? I could have sworn you said I 'played it expertly'."

That is, because the pianist is still only an apprentice, he doesn't believe his performance was expert at all.

Normally, *Sorry* in this use would be punctuated with a question mark.

As far as "a humble expression to be used when praised," *Sorry* on its own is not. It's the explanatory sentence which follows it which is the self-deprecating statement.